# Meaning of `expr "hello" : "\([a-z]*\)"`?

Tags: regular-expression, expr

I need a explanation of why:

```
$test=`expr "hello" : "\([a-z]*\)"`; echo $test
```

would print out `hello`, where as:

```
$test=`expr "hello" : "hel"`; echo $test
```

would return the number of characters matching.

And also:

```
$ test=`expr "hello123there" : ".*o\([0-9]*\)"t`; echo $test
```

notice after `.*` I have to specify the `o` for it to return `123`, otherwise it would not return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how [`expr` matching expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html#tag_20_42_13_01) works.

If the pattern contains at least one regular expression subexpression `[\(...\)]`, the string matched by the back-reference expression `\1` shall be returned. `hello` matched `\([a-z]*\)`, so you got it back.

`expr` used [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03), so you have to escape `\(` and `\)` to denote a subexpression. Using `(` and `)` is considered literal in BRE.

Otherwise, you got the number of characters matched.

---

In `expr "hello123there" : ".*\([0-9]*\)"t`, you got empty string returned. That's because the greediness of regular expression, [the longest substring will be matched](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01_02).

Because `*` match zero or more characters, so `[0-9]*` can match zero times, and `.*` will match the longest substring `hello123`. That's why you got the empty string.

If you have `perl`, you can try:

```
printf "hello123there" | perl -Mre=debugcolor -ne 'print $1 if /.*([0-9]*)t/'
```

and:

```
printf "hello123there" | perl -Mre=debugcolor -ne 'print $1 if /.*o([0-9]*)t/'
```

to see the difference.

---

Note that you should always double quotes your variables. Leaving variables un-quote can make your script [choked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/38906) and leading to [security holes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906).

Answer (score 3):

It's right there in the man page, E.G.  http://ss64.com/bash/expr.html

> Pattern matches return the string matched between ( and ) or null;
>   if ( and ) are not used, they return the number of characters
>   matched or 0.

Comment: @Yangfan: You mean why `\(` and `\)` were used instead of `(` and `)` as above link said?

Comment: @cuonglm I was looking for an answer as to why substring pattern is only matched if characters before and after the pattern are specified? if this confuses you I can update my question with an example

Comment: @Yangfan: I updated my answer with more details. Please remove chatty comments. Thanks.